# how to solve django-query

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

```
class Userdata(models.Model):
    Username=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Email=models.EmailField(unique=True,primary_key=True)
    Password1=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Password2=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    City=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Email

class publish(models.Model):
    Userid=models.ForeignKey(Userdata,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tittle=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    contend=models.TextField(max_length=20000)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.tittle
```

how to find Top 3 publishers who published more numbers of contend along with they email(query)

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know how your `contend` is sorted, you might need to try both these (these two are exact opposites of each other: the first one is first three, the second one is last three):

```py
qs = publish.objects.order_by('contend')[:3]
qs = publish.objects.order_by('contend')[-3:]
```

So then you will have a list. You can then retrieve the email by

```py
for i in range(3):
    user = Userdata.objects.get(pk=qs[i].Userid)
    email = user.Email

# if you want a list:
emails = [Userdata.objects.get(pk=qs[i].Userid).Email for i in range(3)]
```